# How to randomly choose a word from text and also reverse the same word when chosen

Tags: java

I would like to choose a word from a text file. Print that word and also print the same word in reverse. When I run the code, I have the output below. I just need to print the same word in reverse. But when I call the reverse method in the main function nothing prints. [image]

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortingInput {

    private static Scanner file;
    private static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();


    private static void openFile(){

        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File("word-file.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            System.out.println("IOEXCEPION");
        }   
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        file.close();
    }

    private static void randomFile() {

        Random r = new Random();

        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            words.add(file.nextLine());
        }

        String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt(words.size()));
        Collections.shuffle(words);
        System.out.println(randomWord);
    }

    private static void reverse(ArrayList<String> array){

        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            String element = array.get(i);
            String setter = " ";

            for(int k = 0; k < element.length(); k++){
                char temp = element.charAt(element.length()- k - 1);
                setter += temp; 
            }

            array.set(i, setter);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        openFile();
        System.out.print("Before: ");
        randomFile();

        System.out.print("After: ");
        reverse(words);**
    }
}
```

Comment: surely them you want a method that takes `randomWord` as a parameter, which then reverses it and prints it.  Why reverse the whole array?

Comment: Are you using this approach to reverse the `String` because it is required by the assignment, or are you free to use any Core Java approach you want?  If the answer be the latter, have a look at my solution below.

Comment: It will not print because you donot have code to print in the method `reverse`. Simply add `System.out.println()` at the end of the `reverse` method.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to reverse the whole `ArrayList` of strings.**

Remove `private static void reverse(ArrayList<String> array)` method, make `randomFile()`return a `String` which will be reversed. `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` classes have this `reverse()` method for reversing strings.

I also suggest you rename `randomFile()` to `randomWord()` since you're randomizing words not files.

**randomWord():**

```
private static String randomWord() {

    Random r = new Random();

    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        words.add(file.nextLine());
    }

    String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt(words.size()));
    // Collections.shuffle(words); -> this is not needed since randomWord is already produced.

    return randomWord;
}
```

**main():**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    openFile();
    String random = randomWord();
    System.out.println("Before: " + random);
    System.out.print("After: " + new StringBuilder(random).reverse() );

}
```

Sample output:

```
Before: hallow
After: wollah
```

Comment: why do you do `Collections.shuffle(words);`?

Comment: I have a text file and I want the words in the text to basically shuffle the words. So when you run the program a different word will show up, so thats why the Collections.shuffle() comes to place. @ScaryWombat ........I actually got the program to work now because raymelfrancisco also showed an easier way of doing this approach. Thanks for your help as well.

Comment: @ScaryWombat `Collections.shuffle(words);` is a part of asker's original code. Thank you for pointing that out. I now realized it's not needed by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The code would be much shorter if you use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from [Apache Common IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) and StringBuilder. An example is:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        File file = new File( "word-file.txt" );
        try
        {
            List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines( file );
            Random random=new Random();
            String before=lines.get(random.nextInt(lines.size()));
            System.out.println("Before:"+before);
            System.out.println("After:"+ new StringBuilder(before).reverse());
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```